# Peripherial vision vs. results of eye-tracking?

Tags: eye-tracking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Peripherial vision vs. results of eye-tracking?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/peripherial-vision-vs-results-of-eye-tracking)

I have found this article on the psychology of UX, and at the 10. bullet point the article points out the following statement!

http://uxmag.com/design/the-psychologists-view-of-ux-design

"**Research shows** that people use peripheral vision to get the "gist" of what they are looking at. Eye tracking studies are interesting, but just because someone is looking at something straight on doesn't mean they are paying attention to it." - **what research, because there is no link**

**Do you have any evidence of this? Or have you ever studied/examined/researched in this topic?**